# selenium webdriver python not functioning properly

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run the following code to log into a web app, but it is not working. I am getting the result "FAILED (errors=1)". Can someone explain what the issue is here? It should be a simple log in, but I am not seeing the web driver type in the username or password.

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    username = "example"
    password = "example"

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.crowdfireapp.com")

    def test_Login(self):
        signInButtonSelector = ".btn-primary-outline"
        signInTwitterButtonSelector = "#signinModal > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(3)"
        emailFieldSelector = "div.row:nth-child(2) > label:nth-child(1)"
        passFieldSelector = "#password"

        emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(emailFieldSelector))
        passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(passFieldSelector))

        emailFieldElement.send_keys(username)
        passFieldElement.send_keys(password)
        passFieldElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)



    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I couldn't find `emailFieldID` in `lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID)`, did you intended this?

Comment: no I didn't intend that. I fixed it so that it finds the elements by selectors (which are defined at the top of the test_login method, but I am getting the same result.

Comment: Ok, let's see. would you update your code to review again?

Comment: okay, I updated it

Comment: I couldn't find any login form at `"http://www.crowdfireapp.com"`, are you trying to input value for twitter login?

Comment: no, I was trying to sign via the signin button

Comment: Really? I couldn't find any form in "http://www.crowdfireapp.com". and your code is related with twitter login form not other form.

Comment: And your code didn't click any `signIn`button.

Answer (score 0):

You can get twitter login page with `https://accounts.crowdfireapp.com/auth/twitter?rememberMe=true&firebotVersion=2.1` not `http://www.crowdfireapp.com`.

then your code'll work with below:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("https://accounts.crowdfireapp.com/auth/twitter?rememberMe=true&firebotVersion=2.1")



def test_Login(self):
    signInButtonSelector = ".btn-primary-outline"
    signInTwitterButtonSelector = "#signinModal > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(3)"
    emailFieldSelector = "#username_or_email"
    passFieldSelector = "#password"

    emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(emailFieldSelector))
    passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(passFieldSelector))

    emailFieldElement.send_keys(username)
    passFieldElement.send_keys(password)
    passFieldElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```